# How to pass parameter through form_for when it involves more than models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to rails and trying to create an application by myself for ToDo list.

How to pass the parameters "category name" and "task description" in the below form.

users/show/html.erb

```
<aside class="col-md-8">
  <section>
    <%= render 'tasks/new' %><br> 
  </section>
  <section> 
    <% if @user.tasks.any? %>
      <ol class="tasks">
        <%= render @tasks %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </section>
</aside>
```

tasks/new.html.erb

```
    <div class="form-inline">
  <%= form_for([@user, @user.tasks.build]) do |f| %>      
      <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
        <option class="">Select Category</option>
          <% @user.categories.all.each do |category| %>
            <option class="">
              <%= category.name %>
            </option>
          <% end %>
      </select>            
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>    
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

controllers/tasks_controller

```
    class TasksController < ApplicationController

 def create
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @category = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])

   @task = @user.tasks.create(task_params)
   redirect_to user_path(@user)
 end 

 private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(@category.name, :description)
  end 

end
```

Column from tasks table are

1. id
2. description
3. user_id (reference with users table)
4. category_id (reference with categories table)

Column from categories table are:

1. id
2. name
3. user_id (reference to users table)

The parameter I am trying to pass from the new task form are `name` from `category` table and `description` from `tasks` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanna categorize the tasks not the users. So for first you should get rid of `user_id` in the categories table.

There should be 3 tables to connect category to task. Task, Category and TaskCategories to connect those tables  with has_many :through relationship into both ways like here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html at 2.8 (You choose the has_many through version).

Then you create the categories manually in console or via form. I guess you want to determine the categories and users can just choose from those so I recommend console or seeds.rb. Here is an example for category creation:

```
Category.create!([{name: "IoT"}, {name: "AI"}, {name: "FinTech"}, {name: "Automotive"}, {name: "Health & Welness"}, {name: "IT & Data Science"}, {name: "FinTech"}, {name: "Education"}, {name: "Retail"}])
```

Once those are in the db and the connection between tables is set (foreign keys in the db and associations in the models) you can use this in the task form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>  #with multiple you can choose more at once
</div>
```

Don't forget the strong params in the task model:

```
 ....category_ids: []... #with plural you can choose more at once
```

Answer to your last sentence: You show the name in the collection select, but you pass the `category_id` cuz `TaskCategories` table doesn't have `category.name` since that is in the category table. The `task.description` is easy since this is a task form, so you shouldn't have any problem with that, just don't forget to use `:description` in the task strong params.

P.S. You could use simpy `form_for @task` and put this into your controller:

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
end

def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)
end
```

Comment: I want to categories the task and the same time I want to link the category to a user (each user should be able to create their own category).  I changed the create action in tasks controller to `@task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)`  form in the `tasks/_new.html.erb` to `<%= form_for([@user, @user.tasks.build]) do |f| %>`  Now I am not getting any error, but it is not creating new task

Comment: What do you see in the logs? I still don't really get what you want to achieve with the categories. Can you tell me an example?

Comment: I figured that I missed the `@task.save` command. I am able to create new tasks now. I am using the categories in the app to categories the tasks like "Todo" or "shopping".